# RISC-V Linux running on Qemu

Tags: linux, gcc, qemu, riscv, gnu-toolchain

I am trying to run RISC-V linux on Qemu, following the instruction: [Running 64- and 32-bit RISC-V Linux on QEMU](https://risc-v-getting-started-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linux-qemu.html) 
I have downloaded and installed the RISC-V GNU compiller Toolchain

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/riscv
make linux
```

and when I execute the command:

```
make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu- defconfig
```

I got the following error:

```
:~/Documents/riscv64-linux/linux$ make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu- defconfig
*** Default configuration is based on 'defconfig'
scripts/Kconfig.include:39: compiler 'riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:73: defconfig] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:602: defconfig] Error 2
```

Kindly, advice how can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standart problem, try to type `whereis riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` if it get nothing, try to type `riscv64-` and press `tab`, you should see necessary prefix you need paste after `CROSS_COMPILE=`. Also maybe you also need add `PATH` variable with path to riscv-toolchain's bin in `~/.bashrc` or/and in `~/.profile`.

Build own linux is a big task, maybe you should learn some manuals about toolchain and building linux.

[riscv toolchain link](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain)